# Summernote recovering data

Tags: javascript, php, html, summernote

In a php form, I want to use summernote textaera. I manage to display the text correctly but when I validate the form, I can not recover the data entered. Here is my code Thank you for your help

My code :

> ```
> <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>"method="post" onsubmit="return postForm()">
>     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2">
>                   
>                                 <div class="form-group" ">
>                                     <label>Date</label>
>                                     <input type="text" name="date_pub" class="form-control" id="date_pub" size="10" value="<?php echo $date_article ?>" placeholder="Date de la Publication"/>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="form-group">
>                                     <label>Titre Publication</label>
>                                     <input class="form-control"  name="titre_pub" type="text" size="25"  value="<?php echo $titre_article ?>" placeholder="Titre de la Publication"/>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="control-group">
>                                     <label class="control-label" for="summernote">Article</label>
>                                     <div class="controls">
>                                         <textarea id="summernote" name ="summernote" rows="10" value="<?php echo $contenu_article; ?>">
>                                             
>                                         </textarea>
>                                     
>                                     </div>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="control-group">
>                                     <br>
>                                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $lib_btn ?>">
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </form>
>
> <script>
>             $( function() {
>                 $( "#date_pub" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
>             } );
>             // Summernote
>             $(function () {
>                 $('#summernote').summernote(
>                     {
>                     height: 600,                 // set editor height
>                     focus: true                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
>                     }
>                 )
>             });
>             //var html = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
>
>         </script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(document).ready(function(){
>         var postForm = function() {
>             var content = $('textarea[name="summmernote"]').html($('#summernote').code());
>         }
>     });
> </script>
> ```

I tried to do as for other textaera but it doesn’t work

Comment: 1. remove `value=""` from textarea. 2.place `<?php echo $contenu_article; ?>` in `<textarea>......place here......</texarea>`

Comment: And if the problem persists, you need to remove or edit this line to fix it: `var content = $('textarea[name="summernote"]').html($('#summernote').code( ));`

Comment: Maybe I misspoke my problem, but I can’t get the input from a summernote textaera to store in a database.